# Weird behavior on String vs Categorical Dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

I´ve been facing a very weird, or could I say, a bug, when handling some categorical vs string Dtypes. Take a look at this simple example dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'status' :  ['pending', 'pending','pending', 'canceled','canceled','canceled', 'confirmed', 'confirmed','confirmed'],
    'partner' :  ['A', np.nan,'C', 'A',np.nan,'C', 'A', np.nan,'C'],
    'product' : ['afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard','afiliates', 'pre-paid', 'giftcard'],
    'brand' : ['brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3','brand_1', 'brand_2', 'brand_3'],
    'gmv' : [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100]})

data = data.astype({'partner':'category','status':'category','product':'category', 'brand':'category'})
```

When I execute a single Loc selection

```
test = data.loc[(data.partner !='A') | ((data.brand == 'A') & (data.status == 'confirmed'))]
```

and this is the output

[image: First output]

Now, just move my categorical columns to string (I am moving it back to string due to an bug related to groupby issues regarding categorical as described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/50100))

```
data = data.astype({'partner':'string','status':'string','product':'string', 'brand':'string'})
```

And lest make the same loc command.

```
test2 = data.loc[(data.partner !='A') | ((data.brand == 'A') & (data.status == 'confirmed'))]
```

but take a look at the output!

[image: second output]

I am really lost why it does not work. I´ve figureout that is something related to the NAN categorical being sent back to strings, but I don´t see why would it be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly with the difference between NAN value in category type and in string type:

With category the type of nan value is 'float' (as a typical nan) and you can use it in comparison, so:
`data.partner !='A'` will be True for all the rows with NaN.

When converting the type to string, the type of nan value is converted to pandas._libs.missing.NAType, and you can't use this in comparison, so now:
`data.partner !='A'` returns <NaN> which is not True and the result differs.

Basically the NaN in category type is not a category in itself, so it is handled differently. This is why you can't use fillna on categories as is, you have to define a category value for it.
you can use something like this:

```py
data['partner'] = data.partner.cat.add_categories('Not_available').fillna('Not_available')
```

to add a custom NA category and replace the missing values. Now if convert to string and run the same conditions, you should get the same result.

Comment: Got it. I tought the moving a NAN type to string would return to a simple blanck string. I must say that such unexpected behavior

Comment: Currently, in pandas, `np.nan` is interpreted as "missing value".  For categoricals, `np.nan` is used to represent a missing value.  For strings, `pd.NA` is used.  If you instead used the object dtype, then `np.nan` would be preserved.